# Monorepo slows down my i5 8th gen , 8gb ram laptop

Tags: ubuntu, workspace, monorepo, pnpm

I searched a lot about this issue but can't find any question or problem related to this on internet. I am a student and currently contributing to open source . I came across lot's of big open source projects which are mono repo . Currently I am contributing a repo which is using pnpm for the workspace . I have faced an issue that whenever I run pnpm start (or any type of command to compile in workspace) in root directory , it slows down my laptop . My laptop has i5 8th Gen processor , 8 GB Ram , 1 TB HDD (no SSD) and I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

So how can I speed up the compilation process ? How other developers work on monorepo ? Is there any trick or flag in Ubuntu which I can use to speed up the compilation process in monorepo ? If anyone knows how can I speed up the compilation process please let me know .It will be really helpful in my workflow

Comment: That depends on which component slows the process down, but I would start with using a SSD

Comment: Can you run the compilation in parallel (e.g. `make -j4`)? It would probably slow your laptop even more, but for much shorter time.